# Assigning edge weights of a graph to nodes

Tags: graph, linear-algebra, graph-theory, linear-programming

I have got a graph network and the edges of the graph are weighted. Is there a way to distribute the edge weights to nodes?

I'd like to know if there is a way to derive node weight or edge weight from each other.

I noticed a similar post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120340/find-edge-weights-that-fit-given-node-weights), which is the inverse of my problem. I am not sure if there is a similar approach that can be used for my problem.

EDIT:
For instance, for a graph like [this](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/Untitled.png) (created from the commands given [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/graphs-and-matrices.html)) and each edge has a weight associated with it.

Example: Nodes i and j are linked by edge $e_{ij}$ that has weight $w_{ij}$

If the node weights are denoted by $nw_i$ (i = 1 to Number of nodes), the weight of any two nodes should sum up to the weight of the edge that links those nodes. i.e. $nw_i$ + $nw_j$ should be equal to $w_{ij}$,
     $nw_j$ + $nw_k$ should be equal to $w_{jk}$ and so on.

Comment: Hi Natasha, could you please add some details about desirable vs. undesirable allocations? One natural allocation would be allocating half of the edge weight to each node it links. There are of course many others.

Comment: @josliber Please have a look at my edit. Somehow math formatting doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you want to have happen when such an allocation is not possible? For instance the graph with w_{AB}=10, w_{AC}=1, and w_{BC}=1 as no possible node weight vectors such that the edge weight equals the sum of the corresponding node weights for all three edges.

Comment: @josliber Thanks a lot for the response.  I am not really sure if I can do this. There are also other constraints such as the node weights should be non-zero and non-negative.

Comment: OK -- hammering out these details would be key to building a linear programming formulation.